# Ceph prepare disk agsize (251 blocks) too small, need at least 4096 blocks

Tags: ceph

I am trying to install the ceph on centos 7 machine. when I run disk prepare command its failing. the rooot cause is mkfs failing with bolck size.

```
    ceph-deploy -v disk  prepare  cm-04:/dev/sdb --zap-disk
    .
    .
    .
    cm-04][WARNIN] ceph_disk.main.Error: Error: Command '['/sbin/mkfs', '-t', 'xfs', '-f', '-i', 'size=2048', '--', '/dev/sdb1']' returned non-zero exit status 1
    [cm-04][ERROR ] RuntimeError: command returned non-zero exit status: 1
    [ceph_deploy.osd][ERROR ] Failed to execute command: /usr/sbin/ceph-disk -v prepare --zap-disk --cluster ceph --fs-type xfs -- /dev/sdb

[ceph_deploy][ERROR ] GenericError: Failed to create 1 OSDs
```

when I run mkfs, it fails.

```
  /sbin/mkfs -t xfs -f -i size=2048 /dev/sdb1
agsize (251 blocks) too small, need at least 4096 blocks
```

my disk block size is 4096

```
stat  /dev/sdb
  File: ‘/dev/sdb’
  Size: 0               Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   block special file
```

How can I configure chef to use 4096?

Thanks
SR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you probably have a wrong
value for osd_journal_size in ceph.conf. http://docs.ceph.com/docs/master/rados/configuration/osd-config-ref/

"Ceph’s default osd journal size is 0, so you will need to set this in your ceph.conf file."

Comment: yes, I set that value to 0 in the original setup. After changing this value to 2. it worked.